# DOSBox is unable to run c program

Tags: 12.04, emulation, dosbox

I am using ubuntu 12.04 LTS and I installed DOSBox emulator to run TC. DOSBox is working fine. but when I try to run the program on the C drive than DOSBox is closed automatically.

I am using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F9</kbd> to run the program.

See the terminal output

```
$ dosbox
DOSBox version 0.74
Copyright 2002-2010 DOSBox Team, published under GNU GPL.
---
CONFIG:Loading primary settings from config file /home/umeshkumar/.dosbox/dosbox-0.74.conf
MIXER:Got different values from SDL: freq 44100, blocksize 512
ALSA:Can't subscribe to MIDI port (65:0) nor (17:0)
MIDI:Opened device:none
DOSBox switched to max cycles, because of the setting: cycles=auto. If the game runs too fast try a fixed cycles amount in DOSBox's options.
```

Any help ?

Comment: Does your program run correct in VirtualBox with plain DOS installed?

Comment: yea its working fine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F9</kbd> is a shortcut key to kill the dosbox that's why DOSBOX closes eventually on running the programme by using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F9</kbd> . Because DOXbox understand <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>f9</kbd> as a external command to close the DOSbox

Solution:

1. Open dosbox and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> to open the key mapper.
2. A box will open in which all the keyboard keys are present
3. Find the SHUTDOWN text in the commands.
4. Click on SHUDOWN and than click on DEL button below.
5. Save the changes.
6. Exit and enjoy...!!!

[image: DOSbox Key Mapper]

You can change the configuration file manually by editing the README file.

1. Go to `/usr/share/doc/dosbox`.
2. Find the README.gz file
3. Extract README.gz to another location.
4. Find <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F9</kbd> entry
5. Change it from <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F9</kbd> to <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F9</kbd>.
6. Now save the file and compress it again named as README.gz
7. Paste it on `/usr/share/doc/dosbox` again by using terminal with `sudo`
8. Now enjoy.

Comment: I am working on Ubuntu 15.10 ,ctrl+f1 is not doing anything,also I aam not able to get my cursor out of the dosbox could you please help me.